# What is the Microstation keyin for Sychronize Google Earth View for a specific view?

Tags: google-earth, microstation

I'm using TerraScan on top of Microstation V8i and I am setting up hotkeys for frequently used commands.  I can't find any documentation about the keyins for the Google Earth toolbar, specifically to link the Synchronize GE View button to a specific view (View 1).  I know the keyin for this tool is:

```
googleearth synch
```

I have followed some keyins with "selview1" or just the number 1 for View 1. Such as:

```
move up;selview 1 
View Previous 1
```

Does anyone know the keyin to apply the synch google earth to a specific view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too am trying to figure this out, the best I've come up with is toggling the view off and on before synchronizing. So my key-in for syncing view 1 is:
`view toggle 1;view toggle 1;googleearth synch`

this would work too:
`view off 1;view on 1;googleearth synch`

Comment: This works well.  Cheers!